# Expected value of quotient of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be nonnegative independent random variables with identical distributions. What is the expected value of $\dfrac{X}{X+Y}$?

Since they are independent $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$. I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Use symmetry:

$$\frac{X}{X+Y}+\frac{Y}{X+Y}=1$$

Comment: So since $E(\frac{X+Y}{X+Y})=1=E(\frac{X}{X+Y})+E(\frac{Y}{X+Y})$ we have $E(\frac{X}{X+Y})=1/2$?

Comment: Very nice answers. In the question, I think 'non-negative' needs to be changed to positive.

Comment: yup,  it is $\frac12$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on $E(\frac{X}{X+Y})=E(\frac{Y}{X+Y})$? How does $X$ and $Y$ having the same distributions imply the equality?

Comment: if the distribution are identical, we should be able to switch their role and yet not tell the difference.